# Pagination Reference For concrete5 (arrays and lists)?

Tags: php, pagination, concrete5

I'd like to paginate an array (or a list) in concrete5. It will not be a query result, so I don't think the native concrete5 paginator will do what I want.

Is there a reference, or tutorial, somewhere that would show how that would be handled?

Bob

Comment: Would you mind to quickly reference the native concrete5 paginator?

Comment: hakre, the native paginator seems to want the results of a database query to paginate. Not true?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to do this off the top of my head, but it's certainly possible. The `PageList` class (which is what you see most tutorials/examples utilize when showing pagination) extends the lower-level `DatabaseItemList` class, which itself extends the `ItemList` class. If you look in `concrete/core/libraries/item_list.php`, you'll see a `getPagination` function. To make it work with your own list, you'd need to extent the `ItemList` class yourself. Unfortunately I don't know of a tutorial that explains this (nor is there any documentation). Your best bet is to look at the `concrete/core/models/marketplace_remote_item.php` file and see how it does its thing (because it's the only example in the core system I can see that extends the plain old `ItemList` class instead of the `DatabaseItemList` class).